# How to use my own DLLs instead of the one referenced by a dependent package

Tags: .net-core, nuget, azure-web-app-service, packagereference

I'm using a nuget package (let's call it `A`) which has dependency to another package, let's call it `B`.
To include `A` in my project, I changed `.csproj` file to:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="A" Version="2.0.5" />
</ItemGroup>
```

When I run `nuget restore` package `B` is consumed from some nuget source too.
I want to replace dlls of package `B` with my own DLLs, I've created myself.
I can do it on my local machine by just copy pasting the desired dlls in bin folder. But how can I do the same on Azure Websites? Is there anyway to automate this process?
Is there any way to tell nuget not to fetch DLLs of `B` from nuget source and instead use my desired ones?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Hi, have you solved this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Thanks to Shahryar's contribution, we can also choose to add the dll file and set it to be copied to the compilation folder for implementation (define properties in the .csproj file).

In fact, it is mainly to change the content of final compiled files, because after the final deployment, it runs according to the compiled files.

**Original Answer:**

You can compile the web app locally first, and then replace your dll file with the corresponding file in bin. Use zip to package the entire compiled file, and then use zip deployment to directly upload the final compiled file to Azure (the operation of the web app deployed to Azure depends on the file uploaded in this way)

Have a look of [Zip Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've not yet tried your solution. What i've done so far is to include my own dll in .csproj file and set it to be copied to output folder. This way, it replaces the dlls gotten from nuget!

Comment: @ShahryarSaljoughi I updated your method to my answer. Can you mark it as the answer to end this question? This will help others, of course you can also write your own answer, thanks.:)